# How can I wrap tf.io.parse_single_example with tf.py_function?

Tags: tensorflow

First, I was wondering if I should wrap tf.io.parse_single_example with tf.py_function when reading TFRecord data from dataset.map,

```py
N = config.get_num_listings_per_search()
features={
  'qf': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([len(config.get_query_continuous_features())], tf.float32),
  'qi': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([len(config.get_query_categorical_features())], tf.int64),
}

def _parse_function(example_proto):
  parsed_features = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
  return parsed_features['qf'], parsed_features['qi']

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(training_files)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000000)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.batch(config.get_batch_size())
```

becauseThe [tf.data guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#applying_arbitrary_python_logic) mentioned that

> For performance reasons, we encourage you to use TensorFlow operations for preprocessing your data whenever possible. However, it is sometimes useful to call external Python libraries when parsing your input data. You can use the tf.py_function() operation in a Dataset.map() transformation.

I tried to wrap with

```
parsed_features = tf.py_function(tf.io.parse_single_example, (example_proto, features), 
                                   (tf.float32, tf.int64))
```

However, running the code gave me the following error:

```
TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'input' of 'EagerPyFunc' Op have types [string, <NOT CONVERTIBLE TO TENSOR>] that are invalid.
```

It seems to me `tf.py_function(tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, features))` is not supported because `example_proto` is of type tf.string ?

The primary reason I might want to do this is because the current input data pipeline is slow. Will I get some performance improvement if I wrap tf.io.parse_single_example with tf.py_function?

The above code is run in **tensorflow-gpu==2.0**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.py_function` is meant to wrap external Python libraries like PIL or scipy, not TensorFlow operations like `tf.io.parse_single_example`. Adding `tf.py_function` here will probably make performance worse by forcing TensorFlow to call into Python instead of doing the parsing in C++.

The [TFRecord guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord#read_the_tfrecord_file) gives an example of using `tf.io.parse_single_example`:

```
raw_image_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('images.tfrecords')

# Create a dictionary describing the features.
image_feature_description = {
    'height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'depth': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image_raw': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
}

def _parse_image_function(example_proto):
  # Parse the input tf.Example proto using the dictionary above.
  return tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, image_feature_description)

parsed_image_dataset = raw_image_dataset.map(_parse_image_function)
```